# npm doesn't work with node v0.8.5?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm deploying a Node app to Heroku and get the following error.  If npm doesn't work with recent versions of Node, what are we supposed to use for a package manager?  I really liked node_modules and package.json.  It seemed very logical.

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.8.5
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.8.5
       Required: node@0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're specifying Node.js `0.8.x` via `"engines"` in your `package.json`, you may also need to set a version for `"npm"`:

```
{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm":  "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

From the [Heroku Dev Center for Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions):

> If you do not specify a version, you will get the following defaults:
>
> - Node.js: `0.4.7`
> - npm: `1.0.106`

That page also includes links to supported version manifests for both.

Answer (score 0):

You've simply got an obsolete version of npm: the current version is 1.1.45 and works just fine with 0.8.x versions of node.

Comment: This is running on Heroku... I don't think I can upgrade Heroku's npm, can I?  Running "heroku run bash" (to give me a sandboxed bash console) and then "npm" doesn't show me anything.